# slide down animation with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, php, animation, dynamic

i want to build a shopping cart to my website. This page dynamicly displays all the items someone has chosen prior in a list. 
For every item i want to make a slide down toggle link to display more options for each item

HTML and PHP

```html
<p>
  <span id="inquiryCartSlideDown" class="linkArrow">change order</span>
</p>
<div id="moreInfoInquiryCart" class="collapse">
    my div with labels and inputs
</div>
```

My PHP echos this div as often as the customer has purchased items through a foreach loop. So i get this same div multiple times with the same id.

JS

```js
`$(function(){
 $("#inquiryCartSlideDown").click(function(){
     $("#moreInfoInquiryCart").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});`
```

This works but only for the first item. The problem is probably that i am using id's. But what should i do instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `on` function of JQuery which works for dynamic elements as well:-

```
$(function(){
    $('.linkArrow').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest(".collapse").slideToggle("slow"); 
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.!!

Comment: thanks. this works for me.   (I ended up changing class names but this doesnt change the concept) Also i  ended up needing &(this).next but maybe i just communicated my problem wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First keep `display:none` the div which you want to Slide Toggle. Like this.

HTML Code.

```
<p>
    <span id="inquiryCartSlideDown" class="linkArrow">change order</span>
</p>
<div id="moreInfoInquiryCart" class="collapse" style="display: none;">
    my div with labels and inputs
</div>
```

jQuery Code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.linkArrow').on('click', function() {
        $('#moreInfoInquiryCart').slideToggle(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: you are right about the display:none     My class collapse does this for me. I didnt specify this.